# Is $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{f(t+o(t))}{f(t)}=1$ for bounded continuous function $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $o(t)$ denote any continuous function with $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{o(t)}{t}=0$.

I wonder if $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{f(t+o(t))}{f(t)}=1$ for bounded continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R$.

The boundedness condition is necessary since this clearly fails for exponential functions.

I am trying to find a good counterexample like $\sin(e^{t+\sqrt t})/\sin(e^{t})$. Seem to fail by plotting.

Comment: Your example is good. The limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{f (t + \sqrt{t})}{f (t)}$, where $f (t) = \sin (e^t)$, does not exist.

Comment: $f(t)=e^{-t}, \alpha (t)=\sqrt t$.